# How proxychains works

Tags: proxy, proxychains, isp

I am accessing the Internet using my ISP's proxy that blocks many services like netcat. So I installed proxychains and now I can use netcat.

I did not add any external proxy IP to the proxychains configuration file. I just added my ISP proxy on it. I can see packets being sent to my ISP proxy directly.

So how is it working?

proxychains.conf:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.   
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
#dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
strict_chain  
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app 
#
#random_chain 
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000 

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#           http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]

http    Isp proxy   Isp port    username    password
https   Isp proxy   Isp port    username    password
ftp     Isp proxy   Isp port   username      password
socks   Isp proxy   Isp port   username      password



# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
#socks4     127.0.0.1 9050
```

Comment: Usually on proxychains.conf file you set a proxylist, tor or similar can be used if installed and putting `socks5 127.0.0.1 9050` on the file. Do you mean you put only one line with your ISP's proxy and now everything works? Can you put the line? (put x.x.x.x to keep privacy and the same if you use user/pass). Do you use strict_chain? In theory is the same if you only have set one proxy. At first sight it makes no sense... which O.S do you have? Linux I guess... how do you configure your system when using your ISP's proxy?

Comment: yes I added my proxy in place of tor proxy,i removed tor proxy and did not do anything.I am using ubuntu 16.10. I configure my isp just by setting proxy in system settings.

Comment: Netcat isn't a protocol, so your conclusion that the ISP is blocking is probably not why it started working again. Fundamentally, what are you trying to do?

Comment: they are detecting the packets and blocking and ssh also started working which was previously not i just want to know if my packet is directed to some external proxy in proxychains by default

Comment: If you are starting to learn, buying a VPN/OpenVPN service is a decent idea. Especially if you have an ISP that might start complaining about unusual traffic.

Comment: If you had been using tor (and needed it), then you should take a look at the TorBrowser (https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en), or something like TAILS (https://tails.boum.org/).

Comment: where did tor come into picture in the scenario

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne please do not make spacing edits to try and bump the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it whats happening is when i do netcat somehow my request is directly destined to the given address not to the proxy but when i do netstat with proxychains ,proxychains is directing my request to my proxy server then my proxy is making connection with the address and response is redirected to me.